# Bounded and non-constant sum of unbounded functions

Tags: real-analysis

Are there unbounded smooth functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f+g$ is bounded and non-constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=sin(x)-x$